# Chrome application mode: blurry bad taskbar icon

Tags: google-chrome

when running `chrome --app=file://path_to_local/index.html`

it gives blurry zoomed taskbar icon, which is not convenient

I tried different sizes for favicon, but the problem still existing

I also tried using a launcher.desktop file with custom Icon, but it still the same.

> The problem also exists on windows, but less blurry than linux.

## index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title style="font-weight: bold;">My App</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-svg" href="./asset/robot.svg" sizes="all">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./asset/out.ico" type="image/x-icon"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-svg" href="./asset/output16x16.png" sizes="16x16"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-svg" href="./asset/output32x32.png" sizes="32x32"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./asset/output64x64.png" sizes="64x64"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-svg" href="./asset/output128x128.png" sizes="128x128"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-svg" href="./asset/output256x256.png" sizes="256x256"> -->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe related https://superuser.com/q/16827

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Please share any new findings you have.

Comment: @MMM, No I have not. but I used a workaround for this, I used Python's PyQt5's QWebEngineView widget as a frameless window. now managing window icon is easy using PyQt method ```self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('/path/to/icon.png'))```